# Filter out specific timestamp inside Google Sheets Query

Tags: google-sheets

How can I filter out the highlighted cell (01/01/1900 09:00:00) inside the query function I am using?

https://ibb.co/1rjQXRT

I tried to do `where Col13!= '01/01/1900 09:00:00'` (Col13 is 'Date Received') but this filters out everything (instead of filtering out just this cell)

Answer (score 0):

If you're filtering by date and time you should preceed it with `datetime` and format `yyyy-Mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

```
where Col13!= datetime '1900-01-01 09:00:00'"
```

Comment: So after adding the above, it gives me:

`QUERY(importData(RANGE),"SELECT Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col8,Col9,Col13 where Col13!= datetime '1900-01-01 09:00:00' order by Col13 asc, Col4 desc,Col3 asc")`


But this generates a blank result set. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you try with:  `=QUERY(importData(RANGE),"SELECT Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col8,Col9,Col13 where Col13 is not null OR Col13 > datetime '1900-01-01 09:00:00' order by Col13 asc, Col4 desc,Col3 asc")`  Apparently exact comparisons are not that great, but greater or smaller works better. Try with that and let me know!

Comment: Hmmm doesn't seem to work either. It works in filtering out blanks (which it shouldn't btw) but the actual date in question remains. See image. https://ibb.co/L1L0q27